# django-timezones: how to use this app?

Tags: python, django, timezone

I'm trying to use django-timezones but can't find any document relating to it. I read some codes of it and got totally lost. For example, LocalizedDateTimeField of the model has a constructor like:

```
def __init__(self, verbose_name=None, name=None, timezone=None, **kwargs):
```

timezone is an argument. But how can a model field know beforehand what localised timezone it should be? As per my understanding, the best practice should be that all the timestamps are stored as UTC time and only convert it to local time when showing to users. So this field totally doesn't make any sense to me. It appears to me that you have to pass a timezone to this field when you are defining a model. But timezones are agonistic to model since users can be from different timezones.

Answer (score 0):

Three places to look ...

- [www.asynchronous.prg/blog](http://www.asynchronous.org/blog/archives/2009/10/10/django-timezone-view-handling)
- [blog.abourget.net](http://blog.abourget.net/2009/4/23/python-timezone-sweetness/)  and
- [pytz.sourceforge.net](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Well, the links don't answer my specific questions regarding this app

Comment: Maybe it can't be localized to different timezones simultaneously, but localized always to one particular timezone for a particular app.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else looking how to use this module, check the tests under timezones/timezones_tests/tests.py. They give a clear idea on how to use it.